# Trim or remove characters of type (0x0000)

Tags: c#, xml

I have written a C# application that is extracting all of the text that is contained in the pdf and store it in a database.

The problem I have is when reusing the stored information and displaying it on my website with XML. I get an error that states something like invalid character 0x0000, and from what I have read, the 0x0000 character isn't allowed in XML.

So, my question is; Does anyone know how I can remove all characters of type 0x0000 with C# before I store it in my database?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

```
string s = "a\0b";
string r = s.Replace('\0',' ');
```